# How to store multiple values in cookie using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have created a dynamic list (i.e., `a` tag inside `li` tag) using jQuery. When I click on a link in the list for the first time, it stores that index value in a cookie (using javascript). Next time I run the application, in `onload` it retrieves the index value from the cookie and displays that link in a different color.

How can I store multiple values in the same cookie? 
How can I maintain previous values always in `getcookie()` and `setcookie()`?

```
function link()
{
    $(".sidemenu li ").click(function() {        
        var index = $('li').index(this); 
        checkCookie(index);
    });
}   

function checkCookie(index)
{
    var linkindexvalue=index;

    setCookie("indexvalue",linkindexvalue,365);
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + value;
    alert(document.cookie);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var username=getCookie("indexvalue");
    $(".sidemenu li:eq("+username+")").css({ 'background' : 'yellow' });
    alert(username);
});

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    alert("hj");
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to support IE < 8, you should probably use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) rather than cookies. In fact, there are libraries like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) which let you forget about such browser discrepancies (the best available technology is used).

If you really *must* uses cookies, though, **do not invent your own serialization format!** [JSON](http://www.json.org/) works just fine.

Comment: Hai ,I developed my coding using android phonegap .I only use javacript/jquery.if it possible,please tell me solution.